# Justify string ruby

Tags: ruby, string

Need to do justify for given string with the given length as,

```
ss = "There is an example to make Justify the text us"

Total length  = 50
```

Required output:

```
ss = "There  is an example to make Justify the  text  us"
```

Here length of string is adjusted with 50 character, by adding spacing after first character "**There**", last character "**us**", "**text**".

Have tried,

```
qw = ""
string.split(" ").each_with_index do |x,i|
 qw = qw + " " + x 

end
```

but cant able to add space

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking I'm afraid. What is the purpose of these spaces and what are the rules behind where they should be placed?

Comment: I need to justify(50 character in each line) whole paragraph in ruby, I did the split up of 50 or less than 50 character in a line with out breaking the words. Now i need to add spacing for line whichever having less than 50 characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to add space first to the last word, then to the first, then to second last etc:

```
def justify(str, length)
  words = str.split(/\s+/)
  cnt = words.size - 1
  return str if cnt < 1
  return str if str.size >= length

  diff = length - str.size
  base = diff / cnt + 1
  rest = diff % cnt

  cnt.times.each.with_index do |word, i|
    r = [i + 1, cnt - i - 1].min * 2 <= rest && rest > 0 ? 1 : 0
    rest -= r
    words[i] << " " * (base + r)
  end
  words.join
end

justify("There is an example to make Justify the text us", 50)
#=> "There  is an example to make Justify the  text  us"

justify("One more example", 50)
#=> "One                  more                  example"

justify("Or this", 50)
#=> "Or                                            this"

justify("Example", 50)
#=> "Example"

justify("There is an example to make Justify the very long text us", 50)
#=> "There is an example to make Justify the very long text us"
```

Comment: Looks Great, Your output exactly matches my requirement. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
str = 'There is an example to make Justify the text us'

words = str.split
width, remainder = (50 - words.map(&:length).inject(:+)).divmod(words.length - 1)
width, remainder = 1, 0 if width.zero? # take care of long lines
words.take(words.length - 1).each { |word| width.times { word << 32 }}
words.take(words.length - 1).shuffle.take(remainder).each { |word| word << 32 }
p words.join
```

How does this work?

- Split the string into words
- Compute width of spaces and remainder `k`
- Append space width to all words but last one
- Append one space to random sample of `k` words

Comment: Ahah. Nice. I've never seen `string << 32`. PS : It might just be a personal opinion, but I find `each` to be confusing as variable name.

Comment: Maybe not the most readable but avoids creating a temporary string. Given Ruby's bad garbage collection that's a good habit for production code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your example code isn't working is that `split` consumes the delimiter.

```
'a b c'.split.to_a #=> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

When you manually reassemble your string, you're adding a single space () where you consumed the delimiting space, resulting in the same string.

As suggested by comments, you haven't given us enough information on how you want to approach this. What happens if there's only 1 word? What if we have more characters than the line is supposed to be? How do you want to weight spaces? Do you need to consider the rendered width of the text? This quickly becomes a more complicated project.

Note, however, that the majority of views—be they mobile, web, or shell—have methods for justifying text that you can utilize to great effect.

That all said, here's a sort of working example that ignores the edge cases:

```
input = "There is an example to make Justify the text us"
words = input.split
spaces_needed = 50 - input.scan(/[^ ]/).length
spaces_per_word = Float(spaces_needed) / (words.count - 1)

words.each_with_index.map do |word, i|
  word += ' ' if (spaces_per_word * (i + 1)) % 1 == 0
  word
end.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reasonably readable way to do it:

```
def padString (str,width)
    words = str.split.map{|s|s+" "}      # words single spaced
    padding = width-words.join.length+1  # how much needs adding?
    locations = words.size - 1           # places space can be added
    return str if padding<0 or words==[] # abort if string too long or empty
    padding.times {
        words[rand(locations)] += " "    # append space to random location
    }
    words.join.strip!                    # reconstitute the string
end
```

It adds the padding randomly so you get a different line each time through:

```
padString("There is an example to make Justify the text us",50)
=> "There is an  example to make Justify  the text  us"

padString("There is an example to make Justify the text us",50)
=> "There is an example  to make Justify the   text us"

padString("hey you",50)
=> "hey                                            you"

padString("hey",50)
=> "hey"
```